# QTreeView How to copy a tree branch to another location in the tree

Tags: qt

In my Qt desktop app I have QTreeview with data in.  I need to copy a branch from one location to another within the Treeview.

In the model I have declared a method:

```
void copyBranch(QItemIndex idxFrom, QItemIndex idxTo);
```

Is there some code anywhere that does this?

Edit:

this question is pretty similar to what I'm looking to do. The question is not fully answered, though.

[QTreeview with my model how to implement copy paste operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735791/qtreeview-with-my-model-how-to-implement-copy-paste-operation?rq=1)

Comment: A `QTreeWidget` has its [clone()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidgetitem.html#clone) function which _creates a deep copy of the item and of its children_. I am not aware of something similar in the view. What model are you using?

Comment: Thanks.  my model is based on a QAbstractItemModel